# Simple React Hello World Implementation

Tags: reactjs

I have been attempting to run a simple hello world react application. I am not using any tools. I have created an index.html and index.js in the same directory. Within my index.js, if I turn the elements variable into a string, it works, but not how I expected it to work. It passes a string in and that string is displayed exactly as typed

```
<h1>Hello, world</h1>
```

I want to pass the html into the render method but I keep getting the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

See code below:

```js
'use strict'

const element = <h1>Hello, world</h1>;
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="app"></div>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The tutorial that I am following is:

> https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html

Without using babel, we can't use jsx. See the solution below and note the React.createElement function instead of passing html directly into the ReactDOM.render function.

Solution:

```js
'use strict'

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement('h1', null, 'Hello, world'), document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="app"></div>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `import React from 'react'`

Comment: @Chris Once I add that import statement to my index.js, I get the following error:  SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Comment: Okay, did moving it not help?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use JSX without a bundler/Babel. You may have to use `React.createElement('h1', null, 'Hello, world')`

Comment: @TobiasK I am just reading about babel. Thanks for the snippet. I just tested it and that is it. Thanks!   Tobias, if you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Chris also has a valid point, I added this to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to use JSX syntax without a bundler/Babel.

You have to use `React.createElement('h1', null, 'Hello, world')`.

Source: https://medium.com/@clmyles/react-without-npm-babel-or-webpack-1e9a6049714

Edit: 
If you plan to use Babel, [@Chris answer in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726524/simple-react-hello-world-implementation/51726838#comment90413410_51726524) (`import React ...`) is correct. `React` then needs to be in scope to use JSX.